# Склоняется ли слово «Косово»?

Tags: склонение, заимствования, существительные, склонение-имён-собственных, склоняемость

В русской википедии страница о [республике Косово](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE) поразила меня тем, что там всюду склоняется «Косово»:

> В свою очередь, Северная часть Косова, населённая преимущественно сербами, не подчиняется властям в Приштине.
>
> В 1910 году в Косове вспыхнуло массовое восстание против централизаторской политики младотурецкого правительства.
>
> Ещё один бывший командир Армии освобождения Косова...

и т. п.

Кроме Википедии, «Косово» также слконяется в Словаре собственных имён русского языка Ф. Л. Агеенко.

Почему слово «Косово» склоняется? Хоть оно и происходит из сербского языка и может считаться не таким иностранным, как, например, «пианино», всё же в русском языке не склоняется, например, деревня Иваново?

Comment: http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_1_toponimy/

Comment: @behemothus, спасибо за ссылку!